# How do I replace empty cells from this excel file while I turn it into csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change this excel file into csv and I would like replace empty cells with Nan. Also do you have any advice on how to clean up the data from excel better? My Code so far:

```
sheet1 = wb.sheet_by_index(1)
with open("data%s.csv" %(sheet1.name.replace(" ","")), "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ",")
    header = [cell.value for cell in sheet1.row(1)]
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row_idx in range(2, sheet1.nrows):
        row = [int(cell.value) if isinstance(cell.value, float) else cell.value
                for cell in sheet1.row(row_idx)]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the data library Pandas in python to organize your data better and easier. It can help you change your data to dataframe. You can simply replace the empty value to something like 
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
if you use this module. You can transfer your dataframe back to csv file again after you clean up your dataframe.

Comment: So since my excel has multiple sheets I am using xlrd to read each sheet clean up the data and export them into their own csv files. I am unsure where I would put df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)  in my code

Comment: I just suggest you try to use pandas dataframe to manipulate and clean your csv file. You can create multiple dataframe with multiple sheets. This is some link if you are interesting.[link]https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html Otherwise, you can you a for loop to change all empty value to math.nan first before you write new row in (this will be expensive cost)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas and numpy libraries have some great in-built functionality for working with csv's (and excel spreadsheets). You can load your excel sheet to a dataframe very easily using Pandas read_excel, then using a bit of regex replace whitespace characters with Nan's using numpy. Then save the datafram as a csv using to_csv.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#read in your excel sheet, default is the first sheet
df=read_excel("data.xlsx",sheet_name='data_tab')


#regex for hidden vales e.g. spaces or empty strings
df=df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

#now save this as a csv using to_csv
df.to_csv("csv_data.csv")
```